# Is there a way to change the color of a row in Post Administration based on the type of post?

Tags: posts, admin

What I'd like to do is have the entire row be a different color - for example, a light blue for draft posts. That way I can visually see at a glance what's a draft, what's scheduled, and what's published on a given time period (I am working on a system for scheduling posts out weeks in advance).

It would seem the logical way to do this is to alter the row color, since there is a CSS class ("status-draft") for example. However, it appears that altering the row color doesn't work since the individual cells as well have overriding colors.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean something like this?

[image]

then here you go:

```
add_action('admin_footer','style_posts_list');
function style_posts_list(){
?>
<style>
.status-draft{background-color: #008866 !important;}
.status-pending{background-color: #F53162 !important;}
.status-publish{background-color: #FFF700 !important;}
<?php
}
```

Comment: woops forgot you can close out php and load the style then re-open. I must be tired

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add this to your functions.php file on your current theme

```
<?
add_action('admin_head', 'post_color_css');

function post_color_css() {
    //Change the #ccc to what hex color you want
    print '
        <style type="text/css">
        #the-list .status-publish {background-color: #ccc}
        #the-list .status-draft {background-color: #ccc}
        #the-list .status-pending {background-color: #ccc}
        </style>
        ';
}
?>
```